# Swift: Difference between addingObjects method vs append method

Tags: arrays, swift

I am currently learning Swift 3 for iOS development and I wanted to know what the difference is between the following method:

```
if let myItemArray = itemObject as? NSArray
        {
            myItemArray.addingObjects(from: [itemTextField.text!])
        }
```

and the following method:

```
 if let myItemArray = itemObject as? NSArray
        {
            myItemArray.append(itemTextField.text!)
        }
```

Comment: The second snippet doesn't compile because `NSArray` does not respond to `append`. Basically do not use `NSArray` in Swift at all.

Comment: You mean `addObject ` not `append` or use the Swift `Array` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myItemArray.addingObjects(from: [itemTextField.text!]) // Using NSArray
```

or

```
myItemArray.append(contentsOf: [itemTextField.text!]) // Using Swift Array class
```

Is adding the contents of an array to the array, while

```
myItemArray.addObject(itemTextField.text!) //NSArray uses addObject not append
```

or

```
myItemArray.append(itemTextField.text!) //With base Swift Array class
```

is adding just an object.

The first one is would be the equivalent of looping through the array and then calling `addObject` or `append`.

For example, if you were trying to add the contents of the array `[1, 2, 3]` you could call `addingObjects`, or loop through the array and call `addObject` or `append`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to understand here.

- First, Swift Array is *bridged* to Objective-C NSArray. Therefore, many Cocoa Foundation NSArray methods just magically spring to life as if they belonged to Array, and if they don't, you can make them do so by casting a Swift Array to NSArray. For example:

  ```
  let arr = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"] // Swift Array
  let s = (arr as NSArray).componentsJoined(by:", ") // Cocoa Foundation method
  // s is "Manny, Moe, Jack"
  ```
- Second, Objective-C NSArray, unlike Swift Array, is *immutable*. To mutate it, as with `add` or `addObjects(from:)`, you would need an NSMutableArray, which is different class (actually a subclass of NSArray).

Given all that, ask yourself whenever thinking of using NSArray or NSMutableArray: is this really necessary? In many situations, calling upon the Foundation methods of NSArray or NSMutableArray is completely unnecessary. You are using Swift, so you should use Swift Arrays wherever possible. You can append to a Swift Array with Swift methods, like `append` and `append(contentsOf:)`, as long as it is declared with `var`; so stick with those as much as possible.

Thus, NSMutableArray methods such as `add` or `addObjects(from:)` should be of no interest to you.

Indeed, the example I already gave of bridging is completely unnecessary, as Swift has a similar method:

```
let arr = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"] // Swift Array
let s = arr.joined(separator: ", ") // Swift method
```